# In ecore while creating a dynamic instance, is it possible to create more than one object of the base class?

Tags: eclipse, uml, ecore, object-diagram

[School---->students](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtfmV.png)

Like in the above model, Ecore lets me create more than one students in an instance of school. How do i create more than one objects of schools in the same instance?

Comment: In UML object == instance. So you are in fact asking how to make multiple schools in a single school. That doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question how you worded it, doesn't make that much sense. But I think the solution you're looking for is just a way of grouping multiple schools together.

If that is the case, I would suggest adding another object called something like `SchoolModel` which has a composition of the object `School`. That way if you create one `Schoolmodel`, you have the freedom of having multiple `School`objects with multiple `Students`objects, which are all "in the same instance" as you put it.